# How to simulate the sampling distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, distribution, sample

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of the sampling distribution, and I've been working through some simulations to that end. For this exercise, the distribution I'm working with is a log-normal distribution with mean=0.1 and sigma=0.17. My code is below:

```
n_sims <- 1000

mu <- rep(NA, n_sims)
lo95 <- rep(NA, n_sims)
hi95 <- rep(NA, n_sims)

data <- rlnorm(1000, 0.1, 0.17)

for (i in 1:n_sims){
  sim <- sample(data, 1000)
  mu[i] <- mean(sim)
  lo95[i] <- mean(sim) - 2*sd(sim)
  hi95[i] <- mean(sim) + 2*sd(sim)
}

xs <- seq(1,n_sims,1)

plot(xs, mu, pch=16, ylim = c(min(lo95)-0.05, max(hi95)+0.05))
segments(xs, lo95, xs, hi95, lwd = 0.5, col = "gray")

sum((lo95 <= 1.1) & (hi95 >= 1.1))
```

I'm expecting  95% of the samples to contain the true value of the distribution (1.1 on the transformed scale), but the last line of code reveals that all of the 1000 samples contain the true mean? My understanding is that only 95% of these simulations should contain the correct mean. Is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: There are different ways to set this up, but on seeing this, I wonder if you meant to make `data` much bigger than `sim`. Perhaps you want `data` to contain 10 or 100 times as many items as `sim`, then you are simulating a relatively small sample from a much larger population. Also, the logic around the confidence interval is a little obscure to me. It makes more sense to me to omit lo95 and hi95, and then at the end look at `sum(mu > mean.true - 2*sd.true/sqrt(n.sample) & mu < mean.true + 2*sd.true/sqrt(n.sample))` or something like that.

Comment: Right, thank you! I was trying to sample 120 observations and that typo was definitely throwing my results off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is located here: `sample(data, 1000)`.
The default for the `sample` function is "replace=FALSE" thus every iteration is using the same exact samples.  To properly bootstrap your analysis you need to sample with replacement: `sim <- sample(data, 1000, replace=TRUE)`.

Also to calculate the confidence limits of your estimated mean, I believe you want to use mu +/- 2*sd/sqrt(n), where n is the number of samples.

Comment: Furthermore, to make the confidence limits a little more accurate, the more standard approximation would be to use ```1.96``` instead of ```2```.